# Trying out Push Notification Example on Advanced Iphone Projects "Apress"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hello all im trying out the chapter 10 example on push notifications. dont know if anyone has read it, its a really great article on push notifications. the code seems fine, the only problem i have is when i use

`NSString *registerResult = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getURLString]];`

it give me a warning that it is depreciated in iPhone 3.0, so i searched for a change i found that

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]
```

works with this but i do not know how to implement it with the code of this article could someone please show me an example how i could get this link to work with this app.

here is the reference code.

```
NSString *hostString = @"http://2push2.us/apress/apress.php";
NSString *nameString = @"2Push2Test";
NSString *argsString = @"%@?token=%@&cmd=reg&name=%@";
NSString *getURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:argsString,hostString,tokenString,nameString];
NSString *registerResult = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getURLString]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getURLString];

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *registerResult = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```